# Is it safe to store timer instances in a map?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

let's say I have lot of timers defined in the app.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class ScheduleManager {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    Map<Long, Timer> timerMap;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        timerMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TimerConfig tc = new TimerConfig("someEntityId", true);
            Timer timer = timerService.createSingleActionTimer(new Date(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(i)), tc);
            timerMap.put((long) i, timer);
        }
    }

    public void cancelTimerById(long i) {
        Timer timer = timerMap.get(i);
        if(timer != null) {
            timerMap.remove(i); //release the reference from Map
            timer.cancel();
        }
    } 
}
```

Is it safe/possible to cancel timers like that?

On other solution would be:

```
public void cancelTimerById(long i) {
        for(Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
            if(Long.valueOf(timer.getInfo().toString()).equals(i)) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is a bit too much iteration for each canceling...

My concern is keeping the instances of singleActionTimers (or other periodical timers) in a map. (for GC clean up).

Thanks

Comment: yes it is a safe solution

Comment: i do not understand your concern, but from this code it looks like you could just use a list of size 10, where the index on the list equals the timer id, as you seem to have IDs from 0 to 9. PS: do not use variable names like `i`, but rather `timerId` instead.

Comment: @SteveC Singleton session beans use container-managed concurrency with write locks on all methods by default, so I would not add `synchronized` and would have suggested removing it if it were present.

Comment: @bkail you are quite correct - I had forgotten that

Comment: thanks for comments, I misread the api on @Resource TimerService...it stated that every created timer is bound to the ejb bean in which the timerservice was injected. First I thought that getTimers() will return ALL timers defined in the whole app, but this is not the case. So the answer in this case is "safe", but nevertheless you have to remove the instance from the map after timeout is called => release the reference